# Find a symmetric positive definite matrix $B$ such that $B^2=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1\\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1\\
-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Find a symmetric positive definite matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

I tried the method described in [this post](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJupOHyd3LAhXJBo4KHbJZAA4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F1174748%2Flet-a-be-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-find-a-matrix-b-such-that-b2-a&usg=AFQjCNFSHaBccfaR0RSdDNniHwous11mhA&sig2=6nFizXn_WUwc_dl_mUUaYw) but it seemed too tedious. Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't seem tedious. The eigenvalues are given by the roots of the characteristic polynomial (in this case it is $(x-2)(x-2) - (-1)(-1)=0$. Now you can find the eigenvectors, align them and find the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix. I don't see what tedious in $2$ dimensions. If you want, I'll run through it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way the other post presents (diagonalization) is best in that it generalizes to higher dimensions. However, for a $2 \times 2$ you can probably just brute force it. Suppose $$B = \left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right] \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, B^2 = \left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right] \left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix} a^2+bc & b(a+d) \\ c(a+d) & d^2+bc \end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right].$$ Then just solve the necessary equations. Square roots for matrices are not necessarily unique, so there may multiple solution.

Comment: $B$ was supposed to be symmetric, so $c=b$. Then there is only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ b&c \end{bmatrix}=B$$

Then,

$a^2+b^2=b^2+c^2=2$

So $c=\pm a$, but if $a=-c$,

$ab+bc=0\neq -1$, so $a=c$

We also have:

$2ab=-1$

So,

$(a+b)^2=1$

$(a-b)^2=3$

(1): $a=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}2$ , $b=\frac{1-\sqrt 3}2$ (or reverse $a$ and $b$)

(2): $a=\frac{\sqrt 3 -1}2$, $b=\frac{-1-\sqrt 3}2$

Comment: Why is it clear that $B$ has this form?

Comment: I notice that the square of a symmetric matrix is symmetric. But I could have missed some other non symmetric answers.

Comment: "Symmetric" does not mean that upper left and lower right entry are equal.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I see what you mean, I will edit my post

Comment: Ok. Now, we are asked for a *positive definite* matrix. So, you only have to find out which of the two possible solutions has positive determinant $a^2-b^2$.